# Downloads stop when using fast user switching

Tags: macos

I have Mac OS Big Sur installed. When downloading files in Chrome or Safari and I fast user switch to a different user, the current downloads are stopped with a "Failed - Network disconnected" error message. How do I stop the network from being turned off when fast switching between different users?

Comment: Is this question perhaps better suited to the Apple SE site? https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just posted in StackOverflow, and they told me to post here.  So many rules.  Not enough answers.

Comment: Do both user accounts have their own credentials for logging onto the network? (e.g. 802.1X or WPA2-Enterprise credentials, if required by the network?)

Comment: "I just posted in StackOverflow, and they told me to post here. So many rules. Not enough answers." - "They" also suggested asking on "Ask Different" (the Apple SE site) instead of Superuser. As you know, StackOverflow is for "programming" questions. Asking on the more targetted site is more likely to get a better response - that is all.